# When using Mongoose.connect with the useUnifiedTopology option, the returned Promise doesn't catch the error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the code that I'm trying to run. Mongo Daemon (mongod) is not running so I'm expecting to get the error in the catch block, but I don't. The code completely ignores the catch block.

> Mongoose v5.7.13, Node v12.13.0

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/playground", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to mongoDB..."))
  .catch(err => console.error(err.message));
```

But as soon as I remove the `useUnifiedTopology: true` option everything works as expected. It enters the catch block and I get the "Could not connect" error that I want. But I also get a warning saying...

> (node:7834) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and
>   Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future
>   version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass
>   option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

So I'm trying to understand - Is this just a bug or is there a purpose for using `useUnifiedTopology`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/playground';
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
    mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

    mongoose.connect(mongoDB).then(() => 
    console.log("Connected to mongoDB..."))
    .catch(err => console.error(err.message));;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to use a callback, I want to utilize the promise that is returned by the connect method.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. I still don't receive the error when it fails to connect when I try to do it with promises.